# trying to remove module in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I had been trying to remove a module from android studio but dont know how to remove this module even after I have googled, the steps I found was unable to assist me in removing the module. Here is the module I added

[image: deviceprint-release-2.2.0]

after adding the module I encountered this error

[image]

Please how do I get rid of this module so that my project can start compiling fine

Comment: u want to delete deviceprint-release-2.2.0 module ?

Comment: you can remove it from `setting.gradle` and delete the folder

Comment: yes I want to delete it

Comment: Done..... thanks a million

Answer (score 10):

Follow this in to this image, your `setting.gradle` be like this :-

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If you remove the content of the module and it still appears in the 1:Project view.

You might want to simply sync your project.

Just change build.gradle and sync again.

Answer (score 2):

- click on your project -> press F4 (or right click on your project -> go to Open Module Settings)
- select your module to remove -> press - red button at top left..
- select your app module -> Dependencies -> search your Module which you have removed -> press - red button at top right..
- press OK.